# Перехват ip-трафика через pcap

Tags: c++, linux, сеть

Поделитесь работающим кодом для перехвата трафика под линукс с использованием библиотеки *pcap*.

Мне не удается перехватить *ip-трафик* на *VPS*. Ни через *RAW-сокеты*, ни через *pcap*. Перехватывается куча трафика, но *ip* там нет.

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, безрезультатно. К примеру, [sniffex.c](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c) при запуске с параметром `venet0` сообщает: `venet0 is not an Ethernet`.

---

```
tcpdump -i venet0
```

показывает ip-трафик правильно.

Подскажите, как перехватить трафик. Так же нужно определить его направление: входящий/исходящий.

Answer (score 1):

> venet0 is not an Ethernet

ошибка генерируется вот этим фрагментом:

```
/* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

какое именно значение (и почему) возвращает функция `pcap_datalink()` в вашей системе для данного интерфейса — я не знаю. но если это не «боевой сервер», то попробуйте эту проверку просто закомментировать.